# Does the Symfony serializer support the Ignore attribute during denormalization

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

Symfony allows one to preclude attributes from being serialized by applying the [@Ignore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#option-1-using-ignore-annotation) attribute to the entities property.

Does this approach only work for normalization and will some other approach such as groups be required for denormalization?  This appears to be the case, however, I have not found it explicitly documented and wish to confirm.  Thanks

Comment: Looking at this [PR comment](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/14187#issuecomment-94797449) at least the Groups annotation should work for "setters" e.g.

Comment: [AbstractNormalizer](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2c14c5fca7182f11abf0a692e471326f14119c29/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/AbstractNormalizer.php) as well checks at least *ignored* attributes for denormalizing into existing objects (OBJECT_TO_POPULATE)

Comment: @LBA  As far as I can tell, Groups annotation works for both but Ignore only works for getters.

Comment: yes, groups should work for both, but to my understanding you can have different groups for (de)normalization.

Comment: Agree, and Groups will give more flexibility.  Just struck me as odd that Ignore wouldn't work.  I am using it with api-platform and maybe on its end?  Thanks

Comment: it looks indeed a bit strange. from looking at the implementation *Ignore* annotation is handled like *Groups* ending up in *allowedParameters*, so basically both should behave the same in denormalization as well. sorry, good question.